# which gstreamer rtp payloader element should I use to wrap AAC audio?

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, aac

I am trying to figure out the proper gstreamer element to use to transmit AAC audio over RTP.

By dumping the dot graph of a playbin on the file I can conclude that the caps coming out of the tsdemux is `audio/mpeg,mpegversion:2,stream-format:adts` .

If I use the following pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=$BA ! tsdemux ! audio/mpeg ! rtpmpapay ! filesink location=/tmp/test.rtp
```

it fails:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1: caps = audio/mpeg
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
/var/tmp/portage/media-libs/gstreamer-1.12.3/work/gstreamer-1.12.3/gst/parse/grammar.y(510): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstTSDemux named tsdemux0 to some pad of GstRtpMPAPay named rtpmpapay0
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
/var/tmp/portage/media-libs/gst-plugins-bad-1.12.3/work/gst-plugins-bad-1.12.3/gst/mpegtsdemux/mpegtsbase.c(1613): mpegts_base_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Which gstreamer element should I be using to wrap AAC audio in an RTP packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its `rtpmp4apay: RTP MPEG4 audio payloader`. Maybe you want/need `aacparse` before the payloader as well.

Comment: the pipeline I eventually got working was `gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=$BA ! tsdemux ! typefind !  aacparse ! rtpmp4apay ! filesink location=/tmp/test.rtp`